# Can someone explain me how the render happens in this case in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

```
let guest = 0;

function Cup({name}) {
  guest = guest + 1;
  console.log(name,guest);
  return <h2>Tea cup for guest #{guest}</h2>;
}
```

```
return (
<>
        <Cup name={"one"}/>
        <Cup name={"two"}/>
        <Cup name={"three"}/>
</>
)
```

Output : [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okWru.png) |  [Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k5Y6.png)

The guest variable is not a state and changing it will not cause a re-render right. ?
I know i should use a state but i want to know how this code executes and why

Answer (score 1):

You are using same component in render but its three different component to render,so the guest variable will have its 3 instances.

1 component 1 variable.

So,if i am not wrong 3 component 3 variable are there.
its working as it is supposed to.

Comment: Why is the Cup component being called more than once in each case is it a React internal function that causes it to call multiple times ?

Answer (score 0):

This was given by chatGPT but i do not know it is the real reason

```
React may call function components multiple times whenever it needs to construct the virtual DOM for comparison with the actual DOM. This is part of React’s reconciliation process, which is used to determine what changes need to be made to the actual DOM to reflect the current state of the component tree.

In your case, each Cup component increments the guest variable by 1 every time it’s called. However, due to React’s reconciliation process, the Cup components are likely being called more times than you expect, leading to a higher final value for guest.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).